# Notation $C(\mathbb R; L^2 ( \mathbb R^d))$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I am confused about the notation $C(\mathbb R; L^2 ( \mathbb R^d))$. Does it mean that a function is continuously differentiable, takes an input in $\mathbb R$, and is square integrable?

To quote the paper verbatim

> Let $\psi_0 \in L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$, then the partial differential equation has a unique solution $\psi \in C(\mathbb R; L^2 ( \mathbb R^d))$.

Comment: You may consider $\psi$ as a (continuous) path in $L^2 ( \mathbb R^d))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is *continuous* with respect to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and the Hilbert-space norm on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm slow on the uptake. When you say continuous with respect to the Hilbert space norm on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, do you mean that $\psi : \mathbb R \to L^2 (\mathbb R^d)$ and that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $||x_1-x_2||<\delta$ implies $||\psi(x_1) - \psi(x_2)||_{L^2} < \epsilon$ where $\psi(x_1)$ and $\psi(x_2)$ are both square  integrable functions?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it means.